# FOR EACH LOOP Container working in SSIS but failing as an SQL Job or in SSISDB Integration Service Catalogs, Even after providing correct File path

Tags: loops, file, foreach, failover, enumerator

I am transferring data from folder(contains CSV Files) to SQL Server database using **FOR EACH LOOP Container** in SSIS. That works well in SSIS but it is giving me an error while running as SQL Jobs or Execute in SSISDB Integration Service Catalogs.
Even though file path is correct and works well in Visual Studio.
Please see error below.
**Foreach Loop Container:Warning: The For Each File
enumerator is empty. The For Each File enumerator did
not find any files that matched the file pattern, or the
specified directory was empty.**
[Visual Studio Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LO0Qt.png)
[SQL Server result (Reason for fail)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wu606.png)

Any help is much appreciated.

I have tried to give DB read and write access to users.

Comment: Are you using the fully qualified UNC path when mapping to the files you want to load? If you are using the drive letter then it is probably looking for the file on the SQL machine instead of the network location.

Comment: Hi Don, 

I am using fully qualified UNC path. It is working when i run as a package in Visual Studio itself.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encounter the same issue. Issue was due to the reason as SQL job was running using sa account as owner but sa account donot have access of the file location. Once i provide access of the file location to sa account. For each loop was able to detect file path.

Comment: Thanks Ramandeep. That helps.
Along with that  I am Running it as SSIS Proxy Account.  That solves a problem thoroughly.